# How use socket.io ack() with Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, socket.io

I'm node.js developer and i developed one app with socket.io with android and i used Ack() correctly on that time. But i want update my java code to Kotlin because i guess that it's so easy to learn and quickly to render.

The problem is that i have not could use Ack() with Kotlin

java code

```
sockets.mSocket.emit("socketID", data, new Ack() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        JSONObject repues = (JSONObject) args[0];
        // todo with repues
    }
});
```

javscript code

```
sockets.emit("socketID", data, repues=>{
    // todo with repues
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin your `socket.emit` function would look like this :

```
sockets.mSocket.emit(
    "socketID",
    data,
    Ack { args ->
        val repues = args[0] as JSONObject
        // todo with repues
    }
)
```

Note: in my project I'm using version 0.9.0 of [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) Socket IO Java library

Comment: hey thanks, but on this moment i'm not working in it, when i can try it i answered you

Comment: i use implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0') but with your code doesn't work and i try change to implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.9.0') but android could not find that. Do you can share me your src implemenatation

Comment: Unfortunately, since writing that answer I have moved on to another company, so I no longer have access to the source code. However, as I mentioned in my answer, I used the `socketio/socket.io-client-java` library as opposed to `com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client`, so if you use `'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.9.0' in your gradle file it should find it. Just to mention, seems like that library now has a v2.0.0 released, so it might be a good idea to try the latest version.